# SC_METHOD in custom constructor

Tags: c++, systemc

In my custom constructor i want to use `SC_METHOD`:

```
class host_command : public sc_module, public bus_if {
public:
//  sc_out<packet_type> out_packet;
    sc_buffer<packet_type> out_packet;

    host_command(char *name, unsigned int limit) : sc_module(name) {
        SC_METHOD(write);
        sensitive << out_packet;
    }

private:
    void write(packet_type data) override {

    }
}
```

But if i compile it i get following error:

```
error: ‘SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE’ has not been declared
         SC_METHOD(write);
         ^
```

How can i declare  `SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE` or cannot i use `SC_METHOD` in custom constructors at all?

If so, how can i achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a module without using the SC_MODULE macro, you must use the SC_HAS_PROCESS macro to indicate the current module for SC_THREADs and SC_METHODs:

```
SC_HAS_PROCESS(host_command);
host_command(char *name, unsigned int limit) : sc_module(name) {
    SC_METHOD(write);
    sensitive << out_packet;
}
```

Comment: the write function has one parameter. is it ok?